# Launch Jquery function when link clicked

Tags: jquery, function, hyperlink

I've been trying this for a while and I cant find a solution, hope you can help.

I have a link to a youtube video like this

```
    <a id='LinkClick1' href='www.youtube.com' target='_blank'><strong>Title</strong></a>
```

and I wish to register when that link is clicked, but everytime I click it will open the website in another tab and wont do what I have in my function

```
    $("#LinkClick1").click( function(){
      var a='Hi!';
      var clicked='yes';
      console.log(a+clicked);
    });
```

How Can i make my link click to open the site but also trigger a function?

Thank you.

Comment: Your code does exactly that: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/CE2k5/

Comment: I don't see a function call in your click function other than `console.log`. Are you saying that `console.log` isn't firing when you click the link?

Comment: I suspect that your code to assign the "click" handler is running before the `<a>` element is added to the DOM.  Move your `<script>` to the very end of the `<body>`.

Comment: add your code inside `$(document).ready(function(){..}`

Comment: does your link is added at runtime (by ajax)?

Comment: it seems it works on the JsFiddle but not on my side. I have my javascript loading at the very end. I have no problem reporting other clicks, just links wont trigger the console.log.

Comment: @AdrianMojica is it happening on any perticular browser or all ?

Comment: I have my link inside a bootrstrap popover, that seems to be the problem.

Comment: @AdrianMojica with bootrstrap still works for me..check the updated answer

Comment: @rahulmaindargi its close to what you have but I have the link inside the popover not on the button. it might have to do with the dom since it works if i take the link out of the popover.

Comment: @AdrianMojica Can you show your Jsfiddle?  how you add link inside popover?

Comment: @AdrianMojica I updated the answer...with DEMO with `popover` Link Onclick...Please accept as answer if it helped you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another DEMO... with Link inside popover as mentioned in comment in Question.

http://jsfiddle.net/weuWk/1126/

Related code..

```
var img = '<a href="https://si0.twimg.com/a/1339639284/images/three_circles/twitter-bird-white-on-blue.png" target="_blank" id="1">TEST</a>';
$("#blob").popover({
  trigger: "manual",
content: img    
}).on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}).on("mouseenter", function() {
  $(this).popover("show");
  $(this).siblings(".popover").on("mouseleave", function() {
    $(this).hide();
  });
}).on("mouseleave", function() {
  var _this = this;
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (!$(".popover:hover").length) {
      $(_this).popover("hide")
    }
  }, 100);
});

$(document).on('click', '#1',function(){
console.log("CLicked");
});
```

---

Update considering the bootrstrap popover.  If its still not working for you, better show HTML or even better show your problem DEMO on jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/AFffL/547/

```
<a class="popup-marker btn" data-content="Click outside the popover to close it." data-original-title="Popover A" href="youtube.com" target="_blank">Click me (A)</a>

jQuery(function() {


    $('.popup-marker').popover().on('click', function(e) {
        // if any other popovers are visible, hide them
        var a='Hi!';
       var clicked='yes';
      console.log(a+clicked);
    });


});
```

_----------------------------------------------------

The code you have shown does do exactly what you saying... 
See demo at

http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/CE2k5/  (.. By tymeJV in comment)...

However if the link is loaded at runtime by `dom manipulation` or by `Ajax`, then your code might not work. 
In that case try below code.

```
$(document).on('click','#LinkClick1',function(){
      var a='Hi!';
      var clicked='yes';
      console.log(a+clicked);
    });
```

Instead of `$(document)` you can use the `Selector for parent` of the `#LinkClick1`

Comment: +1 for event delegation instead of the cookie cutter "throw it in a .ready()"